# Get codepoint for a matched character

Tags: unicode, sed

I want to replace the characters in the range from U+00C0 to U+02AF by their codepoint  with `\u…` e.g. `á` -> `\u00E1`. Is there any sed function for getting the codepoint number for a matched character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such function in sed. Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -i~ -CD -pe 's/([\x{c0}-\x{2af}])/sprintf "\\u%04X", ord $1/ge' file.txt
```

(Works for the input in UTF-8.)

Explanation:

- `-i~` tells Perl to replace the file in place, leaving a backup.
- `-CD`  tells Perl to assume UTF-8 on input and output.
- `-p` tells perl to process the input line by line, like `sed`.
- `s///g` is global substitution, like in sed.
- the `/e` option means the replacement should be evaluated, i.e. it's not a string but code whose returned value is used to replace the matching part. The code here takes the `ord` of the char, i.e. its code, and uses `printf` to convert it to hex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this line doesn't seam to work for utf-8 files, but for iso 8859-15 encoded files. Could you maybe explain, in your answer, what this line does?

Comment: @white_gecko: Oops, a typo. Should have been `-CD`.

Comment: I'm not very firm in perl but could you additionally tell me if there is any way of matching the string against a pattern before replacing the special chars? In my case only special chars within `<>` should be matched e.g. `<á>` but not a single `á`. (Maybe I should extend my question with this detail.)

Comment: @white_gecko: It's similar to sed, just add the characters into the pattern and possible the replacement, too, if you want them in the output.